# loading slickgrid via requirejs

Tags: requirejs, slickgrid

I'm having a hell of a time getting slickgrid injected into my module via requirejs. I could show you my config but I"ve tried so many things that I wouldn't know where to start. I mean, I will if you want me too, but if someone can just tell me the proper way to do it some of my hair might grow back.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the basic require config:

```js
require.config({
  paths: {
    // jQuery & jQuery UI
    jquery:        'jquery',
    jqueryui:      'jquery.ui',
    dragevent:     'jquery.event.drag',
    dropevent:     'jquery.event.drop',

    // SlickGrid
    slickcore:     'slick.core',
    slickgrid:     'slick.grid',
    slickdataview: 'slick.dataview'
  },
  shim: {
    jquery:        { exports: '$' },
    jqueryui:      ['jquery'] },
    dragevent:     ['jquery'],
    dropevent:     ['jquery'],
    slickcore:     ['jqueryui'],
    slickgrid:     ['slickcore', 'dragevent', 'dropevent'],
    slickdataview: ['slickgrid']
  }
});
```

Then inside your module you'd have the following:

```js
define(['slickgrid', 'slickdataview'], function(){
  // Do stuff with SlickGrid.
})
```

Comment: Oh great. Thank you.  Im off for the holiday weekend but ill try this out next week.  Is jqueryui required?  That may have been what was killing me.

Comment: @Raif AFAIK it's only required if you want to reorder the columns.

Comment: this worked great.  Don't know what I was doing but it was clearly wrong.